# Photos won’t connect to iCloud on Catalina

Tags: icloud, photos, catalina

I’m running Catalina on my Mac mini. Photos will not connect to iCloud to sync. When I click on the check box, a pop up tells me I can only save to one iCloud account, and won’t connect? So obviously I’m not syncing to iCloud. 
The only thing that I can see is that in Internet Accounts, I see there are two entries for my iCloud account, exactly the same. I can’t delete either as they are both the same,

I can not figure out what’s happening.